# Android Camera2 Focus Area

Tags: android, focus, camera2

I am using the new Camera2 api trying to implement touch focus and can't seem to find an equivalent to the Camera1 api setFocusArea().  I want a user to be able to touch the preview screen and have the camera focus on that area.  There doesnt seem to be any function relating x-y position to focus in the new API.

Answer (score -1):

Use [CONTROL_AF_REGIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AF_REGIONS), [CONTROL_AE_REGIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_REGIONS), and if supported, CONTROL_AWB_REGIONS.

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Eddy Talvala, please provide an example Eddy